# Classify a sequence using LSTM in keras

Tags: keras

I am working on a binary classification problem, where the network takes two inputs and output the label of this input pair.

Basically, I use an encoder layer to do embedding first and concatenate the embedding results. Next, I am going to use RNN structure to classify the concatenated result. But I can't figure out a proper way to write the code. I attach my code below.

```
input_size = n_feature # the number of features
encoder_size = 2000 # output dim for each encoder
dropout_rate = 0.5 
X1 = Input(shape=(input_size, ), name='input_1')
X2 = Input(shape=(input_size, ), name='input_2')

encoder = Sequential()
encoder.add(Dropout(dropout_rate, input_shape=(input_size, )))
encoder.add(Dense(encoder_size, activation='relu'))

encoded_1 = encoder(X1)
encoded_2 = encoder(X2)
merged = concatenate([encoded_1, encoded_2])

#----------Need Help---------------#
comparer = Sequential()
comparer.add(LSTM(512, input_shape=(encoder_size*2, ), return_sequences=True))
comparer.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
comparer.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
comparer.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
#----------Need Help---------------#

Y = comparer(merged)
model = Model(inputs=[X1, X2], outputs=Y)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

It seems for the LSTM layer, the input should be `(None, encoder_size*2)`. I tried to use `Y = comparer(K.transpose(merged))` to reshape the input for the LSTM layer but I failed. BTW, for this network, the input shape is `(input_size,)` and output shape is `(1,)`.

Comment: What do you want your encoder to output? A single vector or a sequence of vectors?

Comment: Just a vector. For the LSTM, I am expecting to see it can treat this vector as a time series, such that it can memorize the value seen previously.

Comment: You need to use `stateful` option and `reshape` to have it three dimensional.

Comment: Can you provide me a demo? I am a beginner of RNN and keras. Also, I am afraid if we do so, the output layer will be `(None, 1,1)` , which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to transform the input vector in a time series, you can simply reshape it:

```
comparer = Sequential()

#reshape the vector into a time series form: (None, timeSteps, features)
comparer.add(Reshape((2 * encoder_size,1), input_shape=(2*encoder_size,))

#don't return sequences, you don't want a sequence as result:
comparer.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False))

comparer.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

#Don't use a TimeDistributed, you're not dealing with a series anymore  
comparer.add(Dense(1))

comparer.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Comment: It works, but I receive a warming message `2017-11-16 09:48:46.605652: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 14091 get requests, put_count=24107 evicted_count=10000 eviction_rate=0.414817 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0`, even I set `batch_size=1`. Is it normal?

Comment: Sounds strange. I don't understand that error. Does changing the batch size change those counts?

Comment: Actually, I meet another issue when the batch size is too large. The previous setting is the input shape for the RNN layer is `(2000*2,1)` and the `batch_size=200`, then we have the memory error. I decrease the encoder size to `500` and the batch size to `20` to avoid such error. Does it necessary that the batch size should batch the cell number in RNN? The warning message I posted above appears in the first few batches, then it disappears.

Comment: No, the number of cells/units in the RNN has nothing to do with the batch size. But I don't know what that warning message means. I've never seen it before.